# Matlab's Accumarray equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, boost, armadillo

I found a solution for matlab's accumarray equivalent in c++ with armadillo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950807/is-there-an-example-for-accumarray-in-c-c). Although the code works like it should in matlab, my problem is that is takes a lot of time. It takes approximately 2.2 seconds to run and i have to call this function around 360 times. Is there a way to optimize this code or anyother way to implement accumarray in c++ with armadillo/opencv/boost? I know python has a bitcount function with numpy which is fast and efficient but i cant find anything in c++.

Thank You

EDIT

Currently I am using the following function, as it can be seen in the link attached

**Code:**

```
colvec TestProcessing::accumarray(icolvec cf, colvec T, double nf, int p)
{
    /* ******* Description   *******

    here cf is the matrix of indices

    T is the values whose data is to be
    accumulted in the output array S.

    if T is not given (or is scaler)then accumarray simply converts
    to calculation of histogram of the input data

    nf is the the size of output Array

    nf >= max(cf)
    so pass the argument accordingly

    p is not used in the function 

    ********************************/

    colvec S; // output Array 

    S.set_size(int(nf)); // preallocate the output array 

    for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)nf ; i++)
    {
        // find the indices in cf corresponding to 1 to nf
        // and store in unsigned integer array q1 
        uvec q1 = find(cf == (i+1));
        vec q ;
        double sum1 = 0 ;

        if(!q1.is_empty())
        {
            q = T.elem(q1) ; // find the elements in T having indices in q1 
            // make sure q1 is not empty 

            sum1 = arma::sum(q); // calculate the sum and store in output array 
            S(i) = sum1;
        }

        // if q1 is empty array just put 0 at that particular location
        else
        {
            S(i) = 0 ;
        }
    }
    return S;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried in C++

Comment: @IvanRubinson i have edited the question

Comment: You didn't provide any input data. You need to provide mcve example: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve].

Comment: Your algorithm is O^2 complexity. Do you have to run a find on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: I dont know if there is anyother way

Comment: Since you have the output array with all of the bins, it would be faster (`O(n)`) to iterate through the indices in `cf` and add the corresponding values to the output array like `S[cf[i]] += T[i];`. Personally, I would be more inclined to use a `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a C-version of `accumarray` for `python.weave`. It probably could get ported to plain C++ with some effort.

https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies/blob/master/numpy_groupies/aggregate_weave.py