# Matlab's Accumarray using Sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, accumarray

I have the following instruction in matlab

```
out = accumarray (A,B,sz);
```

where B and A is of size 1x957600 and 957600x1 respectively and sz is [1445 1]. The result out is of 1445x1 size.

My question is how can we implement this instruction without using accumarray and using sparse matrix multiplication.

I found this following solution but i dont know how to implement it according to the data i have

**Matlab Code**

```
%fake data setup
    M=1e5;
    A=kron(speye(M),ones(1,16));
    N=size(A,2);
    [I,J]=find(A);
    x=rand(N,1);
    %pretend we build A from scratch
    tic; 
     A=sparse(I,J,1);
    toc %Elapsed time is 0.062737 seconds.
    %Apply A
    tic
      y1=A*x;
    toc %Elapsed time is 0.006868 seconds.
    %Using accumarray
    b=x(J);
    tic
     y2=accumarray(I,b,[M,1]);
    toc %Elapsed time is 0.012236 seconds.
```

I am asking this question because i want to use accumarray in c++. I have a solution for that but its taking a lot of time to do the computation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255975/matlabs-accumarray-equivalent-in-c) is my question from two days ago which has the c++ implementation for accumarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sparse(A, 1, B, sz(1), sz(2))
```

Example:

```
A = [5;4;6;5;2;5;2;5;5;2];
B = [6 3 1 4 9 8 1 5 8 9];
sz = [10 1];
out = accumarray (A,B,sz);
out2 = sparse(A, 1, B, sz(1), sz(2));
```

This gives

```
>> out
out =
     0
    19
     0
     3
    31
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
>> full(out2)
ans =
     0
    19
     0
     3
    31
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly fine. Now i just have find a way to do this in c++. Armadillo doesnt support sparse initialization using identical indices. So may be i will have to look for some other library.

Comment: I was wrong. Armadillo does support sparse matrix initialization using identical locations `sp_mat(add_values, locations, values, n_rows, n_cols, sort_locations = true, check_for_zeros = true)`. Thank you for your answer.